# Generalization of Nemhauser's theorem for submodular functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

[Nemhauser's theorem](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~eidan/papers/submod-max.pdf) shows that if $f:2^{\Omega}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a monotone and submodular function, then greedy algorithm gives $(1-e^{-1})$-approximation of optimal solution. More precisely, we have
$$
\max_{K\subset \Omega, |K|\leq k} f(K) \geq \left(1 - \frac{1}{e}\right) f(K_{Greedy})
$$
where $K_{Greedy}$ is obtained by greedy algorithm: $K_{Greedy} = \{i_{1}, \dots, i_{k}\}$ where $i_{j} = \mathrm{argmax}_{i} f(\{i_{1}, \dots, i_{j-1}, i\})$.

I want to know if there's a variation of the theorem where a function $f$ is a function on *tuples* of elements in $\Omega$: i.e. $i_{1}, (i_{2}, i_{3}), (i_{3}, i_{1}, i_{2}), \dots$ can be arguments of $f$ and $f(i_{1}, i_{2}) \neq f(i_{2}, i_{1})$ in general. However, we assume that $f$ is monotone in the sense that 
$$
f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}) \leq f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}, i_{j+1}, \dots ,i_{m})
$$
and submodular
$$
f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}) + f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}, i_{j+1}, i_{j+2}) \leq f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}, i_{j+1}) + f(i_{1}, \dots, i_{j}, i_{j+2})
$$
(Maybe one can impose stronger conditions for monotonicity and submodularity - these definitions are just my generalizations.) Is there any similar results for such functions?